# how to make a constraint layout scrollable

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

Hello I'm trying to make one of my fragment's layout scrollable but can't reach my goal despite having looking for a solution during many hours. I removed all of the `layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` constraints inside the main constraint layout and also set the height of the layout to `wrap_content`. Finally I set the `fillViewPort` attribute of the scrollView to true but the result remains the same. Can someone help me please ?
Here's my .xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/challengeProgressBar"
                    style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.ProgressBar.Large"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/errorImageView"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/visibleLayout"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/profileNameTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileImageView" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                            android:layout_width="150dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="143dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="143dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/uploadStatusTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/profileImageView"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/nbPointsTextView"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileNameTextView" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/completedChallengesButton"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
                            android:text="@string/completed_challenges"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nbPointsTextView" />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/completedChallengesRecyclerView"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            android:visibility="visible"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/completedChallengesButton" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/challengesButton"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="40dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
                            android:text="@string/current_challenges"
                            android:textSize="10sp"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/completedChallengesRecyclerView" />

                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/challengesRecyclerView"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="150dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="75dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="75dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/border"
                            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
                            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/challengesButton" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please try adding android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" in both your RecyclerView?.

Comment: the problem remains the same :/

Answer (score 0):

The cause is using scrollable view (`RecyclerView`) inside `ScrollView`, so you should put this one to your `RecyclerView`

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
```

But the better solution is make whole screen into only one `RecyclerView`

Comment: the problem remains the same :/

Comment: update the height and width of your recyclerView as below
`android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"`